# What is the simplest reversible circuit that computes conjugacy of transpositions?

Tags: math, code-challenge, permutations, logic-gates

Reversible computation refers to computation in which little or no information is deleted. Reversible computation a major component of quantum computation, and reversible computation is potentially many times more energy efficient than conventional computation. I want to know how easy it is to compute the conjugacy of transpositions reversibly?

## Challenge

Let `T5` be the set of all [transpositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_(mathematics)) on the set `{1,2,3,4,5}`. Let  be the [conjugacy operation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Conjugation.html) on `T5` defined by `x * y=xyx^(-1)` (here concatenation denotes the [symmetric group operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group)). In other words, the underlying set of `T5` consists of all 10 pairs `(a,b)` of distinct numbers from `{1,2,3,4,5}` and where we declare `(a,b)=(b,a)`. The operation  is the unique operation on the underlying set that satisfies

- `(a,b) * (c,d)=(c,d)`,
- `(a,b) * (b,c)=(a,c)`,
- `(a,b) * (a,b)=(a,b)`

whenever `a,b,c,d` are distinct.

What is the simplest `n` bit input reversible circuit `C` along with an injective function `R:T5->{0,1}^(n/2)` such that `C(R(x)||R(y))=R(x)||R(x*y)` for all `x,y` in `T5`?

The gate cost of a reversible circuit shall be the sum of the costs of every individual logic gate in the reversible circuit.

Here is the price chart per logic gate (see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate) for a description of the logic gates) along with a description of the reversible gates.

Each SWAP gate `(x,y)->(y,x)` will have a cost of `0`.

Each [NOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverter_(logic_gate)) `x-> NOT x` shall have a cost of `1`.

Each [CNOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate) `(x,y)->(x,x XOR y)` shall have a cost of `2`.

Each [Fredkin gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredkin_gate) `(x,y,z)->(x,(NOT x AND y) OR (x AND z),(x AND y) OR (NOT x AND z))` shall have a cost of `4` (the Fredkin gate can also be described as the reversible logic gate where `(0,x,y)->(0,x,y)` and `(1,x,y)->(1,y,x)`).

Each [Toffoli gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate) `(x,y,z)->(x,y,(x AND y) XOR z)` shall have a cost of `5`.

No other gates are allowed.

Observe that each reversible gate has the same number of inputs as it has outputs (this feature is required for all reversible gates).

The complexity of your circuit will be the product of the gate cost or your circuit with the number `n` which you choose. The goal of this challenge will be to minimize this measure of complexity.

## Format

Complexity: This is your final score. The complexity is the product of the number `n` with your total gate cost.

Space: State the number `n` of bits that your circuit `C` acts on.

Total gate cost: State the sum of the costs of each of the individual gates in your circuit `C`.

NOT gate count: State the number of NOT gates.

CNOT gate count: State the number of CNOT gates.

Toffoli gate count: How many Toffoli gates are there?

Fredkin gate count: How many Fredkin gates are there?

Legend: Give a description of the function `R`. For example, you may write

`(1,2)->0000;(1,3)->0001;(1,4)->0010;(1,5)->0011;(2,3)->0100;
(2,4)->0101;(2,5)->0110;(3,4)->0111;(3,5)->1000;(4,5)->1001`
.

Gate list: Here list the gates in the circuit `C` from first to last. Each gate shall be written in the form [Gate type abbreviation,lines where the gates come from]. For this problem, we shall start with the 0th bit. The following list specifies the abbreviations for the type of gates.

`T`-Toffoli gate
`S`-Swap gate
`C`-CNOT gate
`F`-Fredkin gate
`N`-Not gate.

For example, `[T,1,5,3]` would denote a Toffoli gate acting on the 1st bit, the 5th bit, and the 3rd bit. For example, `[T,2,4,6]` produces the transformation `01101010->01101000` and `[C,2,1]` produces `011->001,010->010` and `[N,3]` produces `0101->0100`. For example, one could write
`[S,7,3],[N,2],[T,1,2,3],[F,1,2,5],[C,7,5]`
for the gate list.

The gates act on the bit string from left to right. For example, the gate list `[C,0,1],[C,1,0]` will produce the transformation `01->11`.

## Sample answer format

Complexity: `128`

Space: `8`

Total gate cost: `16`

NOT gate count: `3`

CNOT gate count: `2`

Toffoli gate count: `1`

Fredkin gate count: `1`

Legend: `(1,2)->0000;(1,3)->0001;(1,4)->0010;(1,5)->0011;(2,3)->0100;
(2,4)->0101;(2,5)->0110;(3,4)->0111;(3,5)->1000;(4,5)->1001`

Gate list: `[N,1],[N,0],[N,3],[S,1,2],[S,2,3],[C,0,1],[C,2,3],[T,3,2,1],[F,2,3,1]`

The sample answer format is not a solution to the problem but is a template for the format for a solution.

Comment: @user202729 `R` is just the I/O format. You choose 10 distinct, consistent values for the transpositions.

Comment: By the way, the post format is way too strict, and not very readable. I guess you have a verifier, in that case can you post that?

Comment: I am still working on the verifier. I will post it as soon as possible.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but isn't the function f((x, y)) = (x, x * y) an involution? f((x, y)) = (x, xyx^(-1)), f(f(x, y)) = (x, x(xyx^(-1))x^(-1)) = (x, x^2yx^(-2)) = (x, y). If so, just have paired elements differ on two bits; have one with 01, and the other with 10, or 00 for elements mapping to them-self. Then you only need a single swap gate.

Comment: @user1502040. You are right. I need to edit the question once again. I apologize for my sloppiness.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is a transposition? Just swapping one pair of elements? I don't understand the `*` operation.

Comment: @orlp. Yes. A transposition is a pair of element. The element (a,b)*(c,d) is the pair where we swap a for b in the second pair (c,d).

Comment: I didn't read the three rules correctly, and that part makes sense now.

Comment: You say your circuit has a space cost of 5, but your codes are 4-bits long. Doesn't this mean your cost should be 8?

Comment: What does `||` represent?

Comment: @WW  '||' means concatenation.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that the sample answer doesn't solve problem but provide format

Comment: Is verifier ready?

Comment: I have verified that your circuit is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## <s>640</s> 480

```
Complexity: 480
CSWAP count: 12
Legand: (1,2)->11000, (1,3)->10100, ..., (4,5)->00011
Gate: 
[1,6,7],
[3,6,8],[3,6,7],
[4,6,9],[4,6,7],
[5,6,10],
[SWAP,6,7],
[5,6,10],
[4,6,7],[4,6,9],
[3,6,7],[3,6,8],
[1,6,7]
```

[image]

Use 6 and 7 as a stack to push the two mentioned pairs, then swap them and pop back. the chosen one of 6 or 7 is initially on stack top, if the other isn't

Comment: [4 bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijcsH.png) would lead to score 576

Comment: [This is standard notation](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/files/new?initial=N4IgdghgtgpiBcICqYAuBLVAbGATABAMboBOhArpiADQgCOEAzlAiAPIAKAogHICKAQQDKAWXwAmAHQAGANwAdMOjCEs5XDHzz6MLOgBGARknLC2hWEV0SMAOb4GAbQCsAXQvW7D-S-eLF%2BhAkJOgwJA4QjtKu1BGOhjFx4olOAMwpkQAsKT7RsXQ%2BCfk%2BycWO6WXZFoSMAO4QAA5xed5ROfF%2BKnWNSe0tBY7J1d1NTqWt-YWdNfWjkRUT7enDs3ELA5MdKz1O2WWbVYoji2UJ23OOeyeth12raX3tZ4ozO-OPZcsvx2Mfrc93N6DP4DIbfe6RTabM40EAaRiEEINDAAezArBAAF8gA)